# I can't print contents from a vector or it's size c++

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main() {
   
    std::vector<int> score = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    std::cout << score.size() << std::endl;
    
}
```

When I compile with "g++ filename.cpp" and then run "./a.exe" the terminal is empty [image: my terminal]

Comment: Try `std::cout << score.size() << "\n";`

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO questions.

Comment: @JasonLiam I haven't found anything for what I posted.  I searched for 2 hours on how to print vectors in c++.  It gets harder since there is no error in vscode or when compiling.

Comment: @RetiredNinja sadly that doesn't work. I have tried adding spaces, newlines, etc.  I also tried a different wait of iteration like `for (int i: score)`.  It just won't print.

Comment: @BrandonChan Did you try: `std::cout <<score.size() <<std::endl;`?

Comment: @JasonLiam This doesn't change the outcome, and the dupe doesn't answer the question. (Most of the answers there are just plain wrong). The correct answer is *MinGW doesn't work, change your compiler*.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. is there a reason that it's the compiler shown in the vscode tutorial on how to use c++? What would you suggest I install or change?

Comment: Install MSYS2 https://www.msys2.org/ then from within msys2 shell install gcc `pacman -S base-devel gcc`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That's what I've installed.  I have run that command in the MSYS2 console. I guess I will try to reinstall MSYS2.

Comment: You installed gcc or mingw from the msys2 console? I see you are in the mingw console.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I've installed both? I don't know how to answer that.  I followed all the steps from MSYS2's website, steps 1-8.  And I don't know why MINGW64 is there as I'm using git bash as my terminal.  It probably has something to do with adding it to my path environment

Comment: Let me check my own installation

Comment: Type `which gcc` from your git bash prompt, what do you see?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thank you so much for helping me out here.  I am just trying to get this all sorted out before school starts up again.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. "/c/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc" is what I get. I should also ask isn't gcc used to compile C and not C++?  Every time I try to compile with gcc I get errors and from other threads I've seen I should use g++ for C++.

Comment: Yes you should compile and link c++ code with g++. I just wanted to see how your path is set up. It is strange because this setup works for me just fine. Anyway try the same commands from the msys2 mingw64 console and from msys2 console (these are a bit different things)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Okay, wow.  I have tried using the MSYS2 console before and the commands didn't work.  I didn't know the mingw64 console was a thing and running my a.exe in there works as expected.  This basically solves my issue.  I will just make this my default terminal in vscode.  Do you have a clue as to why though this wouldn't work in my git bash terminal?

Comment: No, I don't know. I've had troubles with mingw64 in the past, where either the compiler itself or the compiled program just would terminate on startup without any error message.

Comment: Well, for right now this temporary solution works and I really appreciate the responses.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I updated git bash.  And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue and a solution.  I updated git bash to the latest version and it now prints properly to my git bash terminal.  Thank you to everyone who took the time to type out a response and try to help, I really appreciate it all.